# Set space between elements - margin top/bottom

Tags: css, semantic-ui

Is there any semantic ui class to put space (top/bottom) between components or I have to use css styles? 
Eg. Between two segments or between a header and a cards group, etc etc..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes there is. You have to use the `hidden` and `divider` classes.

```
<div class="ui hidden divider"></div>
```

Comment: yes i did in this way! i hoped there was something without using additional markup, anyway thanks

Comment: To me it seems that sometime a simple `<br>` works for example between segments but other times it doesn't like in grids. I don't know yet what the best practice is that could work everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer above from @Ray, using a [section divider](https://fomantic-ui.com/elements/divider.html#section) gives you a super-divider!

```
  <div class="ui hidden section divider"></div>
```